# Validar un formulario

Tags: javascript, html, html5

hola disculpen que moleste quería hacerles una consulta estoy trabajando en una app para hacer prensa como proyecto de la facultad.
el caso estoy haciendo una especie de formulario donde vaya las partes de la nota(titulo, texto, imagenes, etc) y quiero que a menos que todas las partes del formulario sean completadas no realice la carga de la nota, esto lo investigue y encontré un código a partir de usar if y pero cuando lo pruebo no funciona y para mi es por las etiquetas name.
La Pregunta es si alguien me puede explicar como es que funciona este y como hago que me funcione ami les dejo código el link de código: https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/1767.php

También el código mio para que vean como tendria que estar:
https://codepen.io/sertyron/pen/EzozKm

Comment: perfecto ahora sabes lo que pregunto?¿ y esto para saber si pones algo negativo en la pregunta tiene menos posibilades de comentarios o que onda?

Comment: Hola. Sugiero que incluyas en tu pregunta un [mcve] y no un vínculo al código, pues eso aumentará tus probabilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

Answer (score -1):

Realmente no tienes que usar Javascript. Tendrías que hacer una validación en **html**, se trata de **restringir** el envío de tu formulario si todos los campos no han sido llenados. Mira este formulario:

```
<form action="otraPagina.html">
    <label>Usuario</label><input type="text" name="usuario1" required>
    <input type="submit">Enviar</input>
</form>
```

> The required attribute is a boolean attribute. When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form - W3c School.

Añadir **required** dentro del la etiqueta **input** hará que no se envíe el formulario si no están completados los otros inputs.Tendrías que poner el required dentro de los demás inputs, pero todo dentro de la etiqueta `<form>`.

Ahora, veo que usas Bootstrap, el cual usa una validación personalizada para este caso, y lo que te expliqué arriba debes combinarlo con lo que te explican aquí:

https://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/